# Keras: gather tensor changes batch dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have an input tensor of shape (5, 2), representing five points in 2D space.

I would like to take the first point, then subtract it from all five points.

Reading around, I figured I can use `K.gather` to slice and repeat the first layer.

After applying it in a Lambda layer the batch dimension is overwritten:

```
_input = Input(shape=(5, 2))
x = Reshape((5 * 2,))(_input)
x_ = Lambda(lambda t: K.gather(t, [0, 1] * 5))(x)
```

results in:

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            (None, 5, 2)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape_1 (Reshape)             (None, 10)           0           input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)               (10, 10)             0           reshape_1[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`gather` function is returning values of provided indices from batch(0th)-axis. Therefore, it's giving us a list (length=10) of 1st (index:0) and 2nd (index:1) samples (shape (10,)) from the batch with the shape of (10, 10) whereas we want 1st (index:0) and 2nd (index:1) feature point of each samples in the batch. To handle this, we can transpose the tensor before using `gather` function so that `gather` function picks right values and finally resulted tensor should be transposed again.

```
_input = Input(shape=(5, 2))
x = Reshape((5 * 2,))(_input)
x_ = Lambda(lambda t: K.transpose(K.gather(K.transpose(t), [0, 1]*5)))(x)
```

**Output:**

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         [(None, 5, 2)]            0         
_________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)            (None, 10)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
lambda (Lambda)              (None, 10)                0         
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `tf.gather()`, you can avoid to use transpose operation as described by @bit01. There is an `axis` argument in `tf.gather()`.

```py
_input = Input(shape=(5, 2))
x = Reshape((5 * 2,))(_input)
x_ = Lambda(lambda t: tf.gather(t, [0, 1]*5, axis=1))(x)

# Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
# =================================================================
# input_2 (InputLayer)         (None, 5, 2)              0         
# _________________________________________________________________
# reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 10)                0         
# _________________________________________________________________
# lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 10)                0         
# =================================================================
```

Comment: I have also seen that but surprisingly in keras bnckend API there is no `axis` parameter option for `gather` function and in their implementation they internally set `axis=0` which is the default `batch_dimension`.

Comment: @bit01 Correct. tf.gather could also have batch_dim argument.

Comment: yea, if you see their implementation you will find that default value of `axis` and `batch_dims` argument in `gather` function are `None` and `0` respectively. Afterwards they do `if axis is None:   axis = batch_dims` which will be always true since they dont provide options to pass values of those arguments.